# Generate Appointment Time Slots

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

I have branch timing view as follows. Date will change based on sysdate

```
 TIME_FROM                TIME_TO
 09/08/2020 07:00:00 AM   09/08/2020 02:00:00 PM
 09/08/2020 04:00:00 PM   09/08/2020 06:00:00 PM
```

I want to generate appointment slots with 60 minutes duration like the following. 60 minutes is variable and i will pass it as parameter. I want to get the query result like this

```
7.00 AM
8.00 AM
9.00 AM
10.00 AM
11.00 AM
12.00 PM
1.00 PM
4.00 PM
5.00 PM
```

Exclude shift ending times( 2.00 PM and 06:00 PM) as no point in including them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another, non-recursive CTE approach, might be

```
SQL> with test (time_from, time_to) as
  2    (select to_date('09.08.2020 07:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi'),
  3            to_date('09.08.2020 14:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi')
  4            from dual union all
  5     select to_date('09.08.2020 16:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi'),
  6            to_date('09.08.2020 18:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi')
  7            from dual
  8    )
  9  select time_from + ((column_value - 1) * 60) / (24 * 60) time
 10  from test cross join
 11    table(cast(multiset(select level from dual
 12                        connect by level <= (time_to - time_from) * 24
 13                       ) as sys.odcinumberlist));

TIME
----------------
09.08.2020 07:00
09.08.2020 08:00
09.08.2020 09:00
09.08.2020 10:00
09.08.2020 11:00
09.08.2020 12:00
09.08.2020 13:00
09.08.2020 16:00
09.08.2020 17:00

9 rows selected.

SQL>
```

These are *dates with times* - you'd apply `TO_CHAR` with desired format mask to display it as you want, e.g.

```
select to_char(time_from + ((column_value - 1) * 60) / (24 * 60), 'hh:mi am') time
```

which results in

```
TIME
--------
07:00 AM
08:00 AM
09:00 AM
10:00 AM
11:00 AM
12:00 PM
01:00 PM
04:00 PM
05:00 PM

9 rows selected.
```

---

If you want to use "number of minutes" as parameter, then modify lines #9 and #12:

```
SQL> with test (time_from, time_to) as
  2    (select to_date('09.08.2020 07:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi'),
  3            to_date('09.08.2020 14:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi')
  4            from dual union all
  5     select to_date('09.08.2020 16:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi'),
  6            to_date('09.08.2020 18:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi')
  7            from dual
  8    )
  9  select to_char(time_from + ((column_value - 1) * &&par_minutes) / (24 * 60), 'hh:mi am') time
 10  from test cross join
 11    table(cast(multiset(select level from dual
 12                        connect by level <= (time_to - time_from) * 24 * (60 / &&par_minutes)
 13                       ) as sys.odcinumberlist));
Enter value for par_minutes: 20
old   9: select to_char(time_from + ((column_value - 1) * &&par_minutes) / (24 * 60), 'hh:mi am') time
new   9: select to_char(time_from + ((column_value - 1) * 20) / (24 * 60), 'hh:mi am') time
old  12:                       connect by level <= (time_to - time_from) * 24 * (60 / &&par_minutes)
new  12:                       connect by level <= (time_to - time_from) * 24 * (60 / 20)

TIME
--------
07:00 AM
07:20 AM
07:40 AM
08:00 AM
08:20 AM
08:40 AM
09:00 AM
09:20 AM
09:40 AM
10:00 AM
10:20 AM
10:40 AM
11:00 AM
11:20 AM
11:40 AM
12:00 PM
12:20 PM
12:40 PM
01:00 PM
01:20 PM
01:40 PM
04:00 PM
04:20 PM
04:40 PM
05:00 PM
05:20 PM
05:40 PM

27 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Comment: This looks good..But if i want to change time duration  from 60 minutes to any other value say 15 or 20 minutes.How to pass that?

Comment: I added that example as well; have a look.

Comment: Yes.That did the trick..This is the solution i wanted..Thank you so much Mr.Littlefoot

Comment: @Rajesh, if this is the solution you wanted, please accept the answer and upvote it. That is the way to say thanks properly ;)

Comment: @RobertoHernandez I tried to upvote.As i am new member i dont have required reputation point to upvote it which will be visible to  everyone..

Answer (score 3):

Here is a recursive CTE approach:

```
with cte (time_from, time_to, lev) as (
      select time_from, time_to, 1 as lev
      from t
      union all
      select time_from + interval '1' hour, time_to, lev + 1
      from cte
      where time_from < time_to - interval '1' hour
     )
select time_from
from cte;
```

[And a db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=3f3ad66d5ba60c8f02c27f4f5a1e1632).

Comment: This is not excluding shift end times..Otherwise ok..

Comment: @Rajesh . . . That is easily adjusted in the CTE.

Comment: Great..Your solution also working for me..Thank you..